# Bootstrap dropdown problem with sticky position

Tags: html, css, sticky, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a data table that has a sticky column. In this column, I also like to create a bootstrap dropdown button. But bootstrap dropdown has a conflict with the sticky position. The Dropdown menu always opens behind the sticky column. When the dropdown opens the top end position, it looks completely fine, but when it open with the bottom end position, the problem then begins.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/abhimrann/pen/vYyVLEY)

```css
td,th{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table{
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 tr th{
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
th:last-child{
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  top: auto;
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
td{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

td:last-child{
    position:sticky;
    right: 0;
    top: auto;
    color: red;
    background:cyan;
}
.dropdown.dropdown-menu{
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Menu 1</th>
    <th>Menu 2</th> 
    <th>Menu 3</th>
    <th>Menu 4</th>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
    <td>Hello 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently having the same problem
I figured it out because the dropdown inherit sticky attribute from td class, which make it stick to td position and then get overlapped

I solved mine by creating a child row to show the dropdown like this
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not rely on links to convey your answer, include the code in the answer